# How do you concatenate substr functions?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to concatenate substrings in SQL but don't know how.
Can someone enlighten me please.

Here is what I wrote that is not working:

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTR(FirstName, 1, 4) || SUBSTR(Lastname, 1, 2)
FROM Employees
```

Thank you

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Jus do this:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(FirstName, 1, 4) || SUBSTR(Lastname, 1, 2) FROM Employee
```

with lower: [enter link description here](https://www.w3resource.com/sqlite/core-functions-lower.php)

```
SELECT SUBSTR(lower(FirstName), 1, 4) || SUBSTR(lower(Lastname), 1, 2) FROM Employee
```

Comment: It says no such function concat.

Comment: Indeed this is ORacle. Are you on mysql or? Use the second one. It should work

Comment: Sql lite I think

Comment: OK, the second one should work. I remove the first one, whch was oracle. Let me know

Comment: Hello Zip, how may I use the "LOWER() function" with that command?    Want the resulting strings to be entirely lowercase.

Comment: Take a look at my reply Neil

Comment: I see. Thank you Zip.